# What are the potential downsides of this homebrew contacts system?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, relationship-mechanic

In a recent discussion I had with another GM we expressed displeasure at a few common archetypes that characters tend towards. More specifically, we both expressed reservations about newly created characters not having any friends. We also expressed that Backgrounds did not solve this problem well enough. Backgrounds provide a framework for how your early life went but not the people you knew and still know. The Soldier knows they have an old military outfit but they don't know the people that are there. The sage has a letter from a colleague but it has no development why that colleague is important.

The core problem exists that in DnD 5e (and all DnD systems) characters are created and they feel like they just spawned into the world. Even adding in "*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*" the system doesn't give players nor DM's impetus toward having friends or contacts and therefore they always feel out of the world in the beginning stages (and oftentimes into mid-stages) of games.

Then on inspiration I said something like "what if we had characters roll Xd4 for contacts where X = Charisma Modifier?" which started the process. If we added in a small, simple, open contacts system could we ground characters in the narrative and create more opportunities for characters to roleplay in a manner that had benefits for the game? Other systems, like Shadowrun, utilize Contacts and create narratives based on these people created as associates for players at character creation. So we started defining the system.

> On character creation (after picking Backgrounds) Players roll Xd4 for Contacts they have where X = their Charisma Modifier (minimum of 1d4). This determines how many Contacts they know. When calling a contact, state your request and whatever form of payment you wish to offer. They will respond in 1d6 days. Requests should be within reason of what they are able to do.
>
> Contacts, more than friends, bring something to the table. You may be drinking buddies with the guards or friends with the barkeep but Contacts are people who can provide something you need. They will respond to simple favors depending on their expertise. Need a place to lay low, the priest of the local temple always has an attic room for you. Need to know the floor plans of the current lord's manor (for non-nefarious purposes surely), well you just happen to know the architect who designed it.

This is as far as the system has been designed. It is my hope that this system addresses the lack of grounding that characters seem to have and to add extra chances where roleplay can and will benefit forward progression. **Now what would be the drawbacks, if any, to implementing a system like this?** How could this homebrew be abused or underutilized? And how might that be remedied?

To note, these contacts are not allowed to become cheap tickets to magic items. A  healing potion or scroll, sure. But a +1 sword is not in the cards.

As per comments, I decided xd4 on a whim but I rather prefer it to any sort of background based table system. DnD 5e afterall, is about streamlining so in my opinion an xd4 system is very streamlined.

Comment: While fair that it should be on the DM to provide interesting characters, it should be noted that as it stands Players always feel like they've just spawned into the world as a level x whatever. This mechanic is also designed to ground characters. No one ever is truly alone even in a fantasy setting.
But while this question remains on hold, how would this question be better suited to ask for drawbacks or potential downsides of implementing a Contacts system like this into DnD?

Comment: Do not answer in comments please.  Help the question get reopened, then answer in answers.

Comment: Personally I think this question is worth reopening as is. However it may help to add specifically why you feel the background features that do this are inadequate. It may also be clearer if you formalize the rules and use a quote block to separate them out. Good luck

Comment: Try reading [this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/how-should-i-ask-about-my-dd-5e-homebrew-being-balanced) it may help you to ask this question more clearly.

Comment: Though I do agree with @linksassin, this should get reopened as is...

Comment: So in accordance with the first answer you've given us the problem " characters not having any friends" and your solution 'the homebrew' though this could be more specific as to what they do and how you think they'll help players RP better. Also the thought process behind those aspects would be nice aka: Why d4's? Why charisma and not a table for all the backgrounds? those sort of things. Also the type of campaign this will be used in. this would add little to a dungeon crawl but may add extra power to the players for little work in a social intrigue campaign.

Comment: are these contacts depleteable resource? Can they be replenished? Is there cooldown on using them?

Comment: Is the idea that you name the contacts when you make the character, or are they just an abstract resource that you fill in on the fly?

Comment: Do these contacts deplete, not if they don't die. I assume the favors work that way, you get one favor per adventure or something like that. And yes, contacts are detailed during character creation. I have considered something like making Charisma Modifier free fill characters. So at 20 Cha you have 5 characters you can call upon that you didn't detail. Obviously they would take up one of those slots then. But that's still developing.

Answer (score 5):

### It would seem unfair to PCs with certain class/background combinations -- but it's fixable

I admire where you are going with this, but it privileges the high-charisma characters, and I can already hear one of the players at my table saying, "Let me get this straight. My sage wizard (INT 16, CHA 10) who uses written correspondence to communicate with other scholars around the realm and who knows scholars in every major city, on your system has only a few contacts, whereas the gal sitting next to me playing a hermit-background warlock who lived in a cave for the last twenty years (INT 10, CHA 16) has three times more contacts than me. Huh?"

**How could this be remedied?**  Consider that the game already has mechanisms for assigning languages to characters, and IRL its hard to learn a language without making contacts. Therefore, a system that ties contacts to each language you know (who share that language with you), would seem to fairly distribute contacts among players, and would be less likely to elicit protestation.  You could use your Xd4 method of determining the number of contacts, but where X is the number of languages you know, rather than your CHA modifier.

**As for preventing abuse**, you simply don't let the player specify *too* much about the contacts -- no more than their race, gender, language, geo-location and background. As DM you decide what level of resources that contact has to offer.